# A power series solution to wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, power-series, wave-equation

Find a solution of
$$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\lambda^2u$$
of a form
$$u=f(x^2-t^2)=f(s) \text{ with } f(0)=1,$$ in form of power series in s, where $\lambda$ is a nonzero constant.

First thing I do is to find $u_{tt}$ and $u_{xx}$
$$u_{tt}=f''(s)4t^2-2f'(s)$$
$$u_{xx}=f''(s)4x^2+2f'(s)$$
Thus, we have
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=f''(s)4(t^2-x^2)-4f'(s)=\lambda^2u$$
That is
$$f''(s)4s+4f'(s)+\lambda^2f(s)=0$$
If we assume $$f(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k s^k,$$ then $$4s\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)A_ks^{k-2}+4\sum_{k=1}^\infty k A_k s^{k-1}+\lambda^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k s^k=0.$$

Also, we can written as $$4\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)A_ks^{k-1}+4\sum_{k=1}^\infty k A_k s^{k-1}+\lambda^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k s^k=0.$$
Also equal to
$$4\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)A_ks^{k-1}+4\sum_{k=1}^\infty k A_k s^{k-1}+\lambda^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{k-1} s^{k-1}=0.$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty [4k(k-1)A_k+4k A_k+\lambda^2 A_{k-1}]s^{k-1}+4A_1+\lambda^2A_0=0.$$

Compare the coefficient for $s^0$:
$$4A_1+\lambda^2A_0=0$$
Since $A_0=1$ form the conditon $f(0)=1,$ we have $A_1=\frac{-\lambda^2}{4}.$

Compare the coefficient for $s^k(k\geq 1)$:
$$4k(k-1)A_k+4k A_k +\lambda^2 A_{k-1} =4k^2A_k+\lambda^2 A_{k-1}=0$$
Therefore, $A_k=\frac{-\lambda^2}{4k^2}A_{k-1}$ for $k\geq 2.$

Thus,
$u=f(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_k s^k,$ with $A_0=1$ and $A_k=\frac{-\lambda^2}{4k^2}A_{k-1}$ for $k\geq 1.$

Is my answer right?

If right, how can I check my answer?

Comment: Your solution seems correct, except for a typo: $A_k=\color{red}{-}\frac{\lambda^2}{4k^2}A_{k-1}$. You can compare it with the solution given by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4sf%27%27%28s%29%2B4f%27%28s%29%2B%5Clambda%5E2f%28s%29%3D0%2C+f%280%29%3D1), $f(s)=J_0(\lambda\sqrt{s})$, where $J_0$ is the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of the first kind and order $0$.

Comment: Thanks. I make a mistake for the sign. Can you say the detail that with the solution given by WolframAlpha related to the answer I find here? I can't make them equal at all.

Comment: Compare your solution with the series expansion of $J_0(\lambda\sqrt{s})$ around $s=0$.